How to clip a multipart polygon inside an iterator in ModelBuilder in ArcGIS Pro
I have two shapefiles: a 300x300m grid and land use, and a Model Builder with the structure below.

I want for every grid a 300m buffer, and each buffer is used to clip the land use shapefile, but the result I got is just one buffer clip, (below)

I guess the other clips are getting overridden, how can I get each buffer to clip the land use?

I'm having trouble understanding what you're trying to do. But, from how I'm reading this, I think you might want to use an intersect rather than a clip. That would keep each intersection of land use with your buffer rather that just keeping the land use file the same. It's also possible that you have a selection on your grid that is making it only read one section of the grid.

@SonofaBeach Thank you, adding %Value% actually worked.

@jdavid05 your method also worked but they weren't clipping by the buffers extent. But both solutions gave me insights thank you both

You are probably overwriting the feature class with every iteration, because you are writing to the same output location/name every time.
You can avoid this by changing the name of the output feature class on each iteration to a unique name.  To do this, include the unique 'Value' parameter from the iterator by including the text %Value% in the name of the output feature class (so long as the value only contains alphanumeric characters).
